# How to Watch changes inside a div in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, watch

How can I Watch for any changes like classes or text change inside a div in Vue 3.

from

```html
<p class="font-bold">My text</p>
```

to:

```html
<p class="font-bold color-red">My updated text.</p>
```

I have tried the Vue 3 Watch method but the Watch method is not looking for changes inside a div.

```
watch(myDiv, (newValue, oldValue) => {
// not working for changes inside a myDiv. 
})
```

Comment: Some function is involve to update the class or text inside the div, why do not watch this change or just do what you want when this function is involve ?

Comment: Raphael is correct. If you don't control what changes that div attributes, like if it's a plugin, you can use a MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver.

Comment: This is XY problem. You're missing how things are done in Vue. You watch data that causes DOM updates, not DOM updates themselves. If existing answers don't work for you for some reason, consider reasking the question and explaining the actual case

Answer (score 1):

To watch some properties you need to bind it first, like `<p :class="classes">{{ text }}</p>`, also, you can use [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
const {ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount} = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'My text',
      classes: 'font-bold'
    };
  },
  watch: {
    text(newValue, oldValue)  {
      console.log(newValue)
    },
    classes(newValue, oldValue)  {
      console.log(newValue)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addClass() {
      this.classes = 'font-bold color-red'
    }
  },
  setup() {
    let observer = null
    let target = ref(null)
    let options = {subtree: true, childList: true, attributes: true}
    const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
      for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
          console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
          console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
        }
      }
    };
    onMounted(() => {
      target = document.querySelector(".mydiv")
      observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
      observer.observe(target, options);
    });
    onBeforeUnmount(() => observer.disconnect())
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.color-red {
  color: red;
}
.font-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p class="mydiv" :class="classes">{{ text }}</p>
  <input v-model="text" />
  <button @click="addClass">class</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want to bind the hole div. Not individually classes or text.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a SFC component with your paragraph and catch every change with a hook onUpdated

```
onUpdated(() => {
  console.log('updated');
});
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5qtyjg

Answer (score 0):

In Vue3 you can use `ref`s in template. [Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component)

```
<p ref="myDiv" class="test">{{text}}</p>
```

Now you can define them in template. `myDiv.value` will hold DOM element

```
const myDiv = ref(null)
const text= computed(() => {
  if(myDiv.value.classList ... rest of your logic for checking classes)
  return "Text"
  else return "Updated Text"
})
```